# Web API and WPF client

Tags: c#, wpf, asp.net-web-api

I've followed the following article to set up a simple Web API solution:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/350488/A-simple-POC-using-ASP-NET-Web-API-Entity-Framewor

I've omitted the Common project, Log4Net and Castle Windsor to keep the project as simple as possible.

Then I created a WPF project. However, now which project should I reference in order access the WebAPI and the underlying models?

Comment: Use httpwebrequest class to make requests to the webapi. You cannot add a service reference to this project like you would normally do with a WCF service. However there are a WebAPI client nuget package called "Microsoft ASP.NET Web API client libraries" [link](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-clients/calling-a-web-api-from-a-net-client)

Answer (score 6):

Use the HttpWebRequest class to make request to the Web API. Below a quick sample for something I've used to make requests to some other restful service (that service only allowed POST/GET, and not DELETE/PUT).

```
        HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(actionUrl) as HttpWebRequest; 
        request.ContentType = "application/json";

        if (postData.Length > 0)
        {
            request.Method = "POST"; // we have some post data, act as post request.

            // write post data to request stream, and dispose streamwriter afterwards.
            using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream()))
            {
                writer.Write(postData);
                writer.Close();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            request.Method = "GET"; // no post data, act as get request.
            request.ContentLength = 0;
        }

        string responseData = string.Empty;

        using (HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
        {
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                responseData = reader.ReadToEnd();
                reader.Close();
            }

            response.Close();
        }

        return responseData;
```

There are also a nuget package available called "Microsoft ASP.NET Web API client libraries" which can be used to make requests to the WebAPI. More on that package here(http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-clients/calling-a-web-api-from-a-net-client)

Comment: If I add a reference to my AppModel.dll I should have my entities. However I can also access the dbcontext which might not be a good idea.

Comment: I guess not. Since you are using webapi, you should not reference the datamodel project directly if you want to utilize the service layer in every part of the application. Create some proxy models in a different project, and tie up the json from the webapi requests to those models and use them in your presentation layer.